# Arithmetic mean of numbers in an interval divisible by given c

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, means

Studying Python, I was solving an algorithmic problem:
**find the arithmetic mean of numbers in an interval [a, b] divisible by given c.**

Having solved it with loops, I wondered about *a simple formula* that uses only integer division.
I could not find one, even under assumptions of 0 < a <= b, c >0
Here's some solution with minimal use of conditions ( // is integer division and % is reminder):

```
if a % c == 0:  
    first = a  
else:  
    first = (a // c + 1) * c  
    
last = c * (b // c)  

if first > last:  
    print(0)  
else:
    print((first + last) / 2)
```

Perhaps someone will be interested to find a single formula!

Answer (score 0):

Finally

```
foo = - (- a // c)
bar = b // c

if foo == bar + 1:
    result = 'Undefined'
else:
    result = (foo + bar) * c / 2

print(result)
```